# AsyncTask in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

Im using approach, described in [this](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html) article, downloading and parsing html page in Fragment's AsyncTask. Everything works fine on emulator, but then I tried it on my Galaxy S2. When I rotate my device, listview is not refreshed, and if I rotate device back, its refreshed.

Here is a code of how I use my fragment in onCreate (LinksDownloader - class for parsing html)

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
mTaskFragment = (DownloadLinksTaskFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag("task");
if (mTaskFragment == null){
    mTaskFragment = new DownloadLinksTaskFragment();
    mTaskFragment.linksDownloader = new LinksDownloader();
    fm.beginTransaction().add(mTaskFragment, "task").commit();
}
...
goButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mTaskFragment.execute();
    }
});
...
linksAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mTaskFragment.linksDownloader.linksArray);
linksListView.setAdapter(linksAdapter);
```

And fragment class

```
public class DownloadLinksTaskFragment extends Fragment {

static interface TaskCallbacks {
    void onPreExecute();
    void onPostExecute(Byte mssg);
}

private TaskCallbacks mCallbacks;
private DownloadLinksTask mTask;
public LinksDownloader linksDownloader;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    mCallbacks = (TaskCallbacks) activity;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mCallbacks = null;
}

public void execute() {
    mTask = new DownloadLinksTask();
    mTask.execute();
}


private class DownloadLinksTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Byte> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        if (mCallbacks != null) {
            mCallbacks.onPreExecute();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Byte b) {
        if (mCallbacks != null) {
            mCallbacks.onPostExecute(b);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Byte doInBackground(Void... v) {
        byte exceptionType = 0;
        try {

            linksDownloader.download();

        } catch (HttpStatusException e) {
            exceptionType = 1;
        } catch (WrongContentException e) {
            exceptionType = 2;
        } catch (ConnectTimeoutException e) {
            exceptionType = 3;
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
            exceptionType = 3;
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            exceptionType = 3;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            exceptionType = 4;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            exceptionType = 5;
        }
        return exceptionType;
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation is -at least- controversial if not wrong.

What you are trying to do is to create fragment which only role  is to download data.

You should move part of your UI handling (in your case list view) to this Fragment (ListFragment would be appropriate). Even better approach is to write your implementation of `AsyncTaskLoader` and add `LoaderCallback` to your Fragment -this relives you from worrying about screen rotations and writing your own Interfaces and/or Handlers.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a callback interface for that and implement that in activity. Create reference of that interface in the fragment and cast `getActivity()` with the interface in `onPostExecute()` of `DownloadLinksTask` in fragment. in the overridden method of that interface in the activity call `linksAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to refresh list view contents.

Hope this helps